# Openfeign ErrorDecoder caused java.io.IOException: stream is closed

Tags: java, stream, feign, openfeign

When i try to implements `ErrorDecoder` to decode the feign exception, i found the stream in `response.body()` is closed, so when i try to read the stream and trans to string, it throw `java.io.IOException: stream is closed`. It's really confused because before the decoder, i didn't do anything to closed the stream advanced.

```java
public class FeignClientErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        log.info("feign client response: {}", response);
        String body = null;
        try {
            body = Util.toString(response.body().asReader(Charset.defaultCharset()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("feign.IOException", e);
        }
        return new ServiceException(MessageCode.builder(ExceptionCodeEnum.ERROR));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

I went through this nightmare and it was all the IDE's fault.

The breakpoint in the debug mode was over/before the `response.body().asReader` causing the stream to close.

Simply started debugging after reading the body and everything went fine.

Comment: Man, you save me a lot of time!!! Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: you deserve a medal

Comment: Man you seriously deserve a medal

Comment: Thank you!! I wish I know this a month ago.

Answer (score 7):

**Logger / System.out.println / IDE Debug mode**

*Don't use any of the above feature before get the `response.body()`*

If you use any of the above feature to print / log / view your `response` object then it will process the `response.body()` internally and close the `InputStream`. So in this case you will get `Stream is closed` error.

To fix this issue process the `response.body()` before the logger. Now you can check this by running your application but not in debug mode.

Sample code:

```
@Override
  public Exception decode(final String methodKey, final Response response) {
    final String error = getResponseBodyAsString(response.body());
    LOGGER.error("{} failed with response {}", methodKey, response);
    return new ServiceException("Request failed with status: " + response.status()
                                                         + " and error: " + error);
  }

  private String getResponseBodyAsString(final Response.Body body) {
    try {
      return IOUtils.toString(body.asReader(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (final IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Failed to read the response body with error: ", e);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Note: If you are in debug mode then your IDEA will process this response so even that case also you will get same error. So please don't check this in debug mode.

Comment: This answer is more correct than above solution because now indicates what is the problem and proposes a coherent code solution